# Re-direct a Subdomain to subdomain.domain.com/mypage.html

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I've searched for a similar question but can't quite find an exact match to what I need.

I have a wildcard subdomain setup and I'd like to redirect all visitors to
anysubdomainhere.maindomain.com to anysubdomainhere.maindomain.com/mypage.html

I'd also like all visitors that visit without the subdomain prefix to act as normal.

I have the following in my htaccess but I'm getting an error "too many redirects" in the browser.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^/.]+)\.maindomain\.com$ 
RewriteCond %1 !^(www|ftp|mail)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.+)$ "http://%1.maindomain.com/mypage.html" [L,P]
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't want the `P` flag. That for proxying. You want the `R` flag for redirecting.

The loop is probably caused by the fact that `/mypage.html` **also matches** the regex `(.+)$`, so you need to add an exception:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^/.]+)\.maindomain\.com$ 
RewriteCond %1 !^(www|ftp|mail)$ [NC]
RewriteCond $1 !mypage\.html
RewriteRule (.+)$ "http://%1.maindomain.com/mypage.html" [L,R]
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because when the visitor reaches mypage.html, you redirect it again (and again).
You could change it to this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mypage.html [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^/.]+)\.maindomain\.com$ 
RewriteCond %1 !^(www|ftp|mail)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.+)$ "http://%1.maindomain.com/mypage.html" [L,R]
```

(Note that I cannot test this at this point, so above may contain an error)

Also note that when the visitor visits another page after that you will be redirecting to mypage.html again.
So maybe you'd want to use the following rule instead:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$ [NC]
```

In that case you would redirect the user from the "homepage" only.